# Forgot Password

Tags: samsung, password

I can´t remember my Samsung Galaxy J7´s phone password and I have to reset it. But I don't want to lose all of my pictures and etc. How can I still have all of that stuff without downloading it or getting on my phone?

Answer (score 1):

•Note this is an advance task 
 •This is created by me and I've tested this many times

1. First of all if you have enabled oem unlocking you must have heard custom recovery and twrp is one of them. 
   Install a twrp using Odin you can go here [Samsung j7 pro](https://www.google.com/amp/s/forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-j7-2017/development/recovery-t-r-p-3-2-1-0-t3751717/amp/) or [Samsung j700t](https://www.google.com/amp/s/forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-j7/j700t-development/recovery-galaxy-j7-sm-j700t-t1-t3560342/amp/) here. If you're phone model is not in the list then tell me your phone model or just search on your own.
   After installing twrp power off your phone then press **volume up** + **power ** + **Home** button together then you will be booted to twrp to delete your passcode goto advance > file manager then navigate to /data/system/ and delete all .key files and also locksettings.db after doing those just reboot to system then the passcode/pattern/pin is gone

   2. You need to have your stock boot where its stored on your stock firmware download your stock firmware from [here](https://updato.com/firmware-archive-select-model) or [here](https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/). After that extract the firmware, you should get something like AP, PDA, CSC open the AP using winrar or other archive tools if there's no AP then open PDA find boot.img then extract it. After getting your stock boot you need to download assayyed kitchen [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/forum.xda-developers.com/chef-central/android/best-android-roms-editor-assayyedkitchen-t3410545/amp/). After download extract it to some folder then open assayyed kitchen.exe after that it should create work folders, put your stock boot on the work folder then goto assayyed kitchen then type 12 then 1 to unpackimg after that you need to type the number of the -enable USB debugging by default (I forgot the number) then after that recompile the boot press 2 and enter .
      Copy your moddedboot then create an archive to it using any archive tools archive it as an .tar file after that copy he boot.img.tar to the desktop then power off your phone after powering off hold **volume down** + **Power button** + **Home button** together then your phone will be booted to download mode after that open Odin choose PDA/ap choose the stockmoddedboot.img.tar then click flash after that connect your phone to the computer then the flashing process will continue.
      After installing the stockmoddedboot power on your phone then connect the phone to PC then type  `adb devices`, there would be a information that will pop up to your phone just click grant/accept then type `adb shell rm /data/system/gesture.key` then `adb reboot`
      Your phone would be booted without a passcode/pattern/pin

P.S. if anyone try removing there frp you can use the method 2 but you need to download some software to remove frp using adb and fastboot

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do so...

1. First, if your phone has a Google account logged in go to Android Device Manager's Website and Login with your Google Account...You'll find an option to change the device's lock code along with several other options....IF this fails...as sometimes Google denies you the privilege to change the passcode in case your Google account shower suspicious activity by saying that the phone is already protected ....go to method 2
2. IF YOU HAD A SAMSUNG account logged in on the phone go to [Find my Device](https://findmymobile.samsung.com/#home) and Log into the account which was on the phone...this will Surely work and get you an Option to Change your phone's Password/Pattern